# Why is this row (with a form inside) behaving differently?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small problem. I'm playing around with a tutorial to create a chat room but I want it to be mobile friendly and what I did was to add "foundation" grid to it but it was harder than it seemed.

[image]

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
  body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
  #contentWrap{
   float:left;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
  }
  #chat{
   border: 1px #000 solid;
   overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  
  #send-message { 
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding-top: 2px; 
   bottom: 0;
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: block;
   width: 100%; 
   position: absolute;

   }

  #send-message input { box-sizing: border-box; border-style: solid; width: 100%; border-width: 1px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom: 10px;  flex: 2;}
  #send-message button { box-sizing: border-box; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; width: 100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
  #chat { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #chat li { padding: 5px 10px; }
  #chat li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
```

```html
<body>


 <div id="contentWrap">
  <div class="row">
   <div id="users" class="twelve columns"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <ul id="chat">
       <i>asd se unió a la conversación...</i><br><li><b>asd: </b>sadads</li><li><b>asd: </b>aaa.</li><li><b>asd: </b>aas</li><li><b>asd: </b>asd</li><li><b>asd: </b>sadw</li><li><b>asd: </b>df</li><li><b>asd: </b>sad</li><li><b>asd: </b>asd</li><li><b>asd: </b>afd</li><li><b>asd: </b>daf</li><li><b>asd: </b>af</li><li><b>asd: </b>af</li><li><b>asd: </b>afd</li><li><b>asd: </b>dgbgggg</li><li><b>asd: </b>esto es una prueba</li><li><b>asd: </b>asdsf</li><li><b>asd: </b>sdd11</li><li><b>asd: </b>2</li><li><b>asd: </b>3</li><li><b>asd: </b>4</li><li><b>asd: </b>5ff</li><li><b>asd: </b>sd</li>
      </ul>
   <form id="send-message">
    <input id="message"  autocomplete="off" required autofocus="on"/><br/>
    <button type="submit" >Enviar</button>
   </form> 
  </div> 
 </div>

</body>
```

I want the message box to stay at the bottom as that's to be expected from a chat message box! I  thought using position relative in the parent and position absolute in the child would fix it but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some changes in CSS and it worked.

Here is the CSS:

```
.row {
  position: relative;
}

#chat {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#chat li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 80px
}
```

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/maryamhdr/b4yu3tqz/31/

Comment: On my website it looks worse. The form is now at the top of the page and the message box is almost invisible. https://imgur.com/si1UEMw

Comment: I think the problem is not in this part of the code.

Comment: Remove the li tags. The li tags are just an example filling text.

Comment: I found the problem. Set "height" for the #chat. Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/maryamhdr/b4yu3tqz/5/

Comment: I got the same initial result when the box is full of messages https://imgur.com/uvfJd8d

Comment: I put the form below the ul instead of inside (because it's the ul what I need to scroll, not the whole thing with the form inside) and it works. It's just that a few lines are still hidden from the user.

Comment: I put the form below the ul and set position:relative; for the .row and it perfectly works. Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/maryamhdr/b4yu3tqz/13/

Comment: Thanks. Did you notice that the last 3 li tags are invisible to the user? It's the same problem I'm having myself on the html file.

Comment: I wish this solve your pb :D I added some margin to the last li item. Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/maryamhdr/b4yu3tqz/31/

Comment: That one did the job!